# Hibernate using multiple databases

Tags: hibernate, spring, orm, dao

Someone know how to add a another datasource in hibernate configuration and how to configure Spring to that datasource its autoinject in my respective DAO?

This is my code with one datasource, that run perfectly, but i don't know how add another datasource. I want to add another data source that is a database with different tables than the actual database.

HIBERNATE CONF

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/personal"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="mysql"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref local="dataSource"/>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.app.personal.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

DAO EXAMPLE

```
@Repository
public class ModuloDAOHibernate extends HibernateTemplate implements ModuloDAO {

    @Autowired
    public ModuloDAOHibernate(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super(sessionFactory);
    }

    public List<Modulo> getAllGrupoModuloDAO() {
        Criteria criteriaList = this.getSession().createCriteria(Modulo.class);
        criteriaList.addOrder(Order.asc("orden"));
        return criteriaList.list();
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ok. I find another solution, and that is using the same method like this: add another dataSource and SessionFactory, next in the method of DAO that injject the sessionFactory add the @Qualifier anottation withe the property of the sessionFactory required, like this:

```
  @Autowired 
    public ProgramaSgteDAOHibernate(@Qualifier("sessionFactory3") SessionFactory sessionFactory) { 
     super(sessionFactory); 
    }
```

Comment: can you please post your new hibernate.cfg.xml file please? i am trying to solve this same issue.

Answer (score 13):

I assume you have a set of DAOs that should use `dataSource1` and appropriate `sessionFactory1`, while others should use different `dataSouce2` and `sessionFactory2` based on `dataSource2`. Of course you need to declare your second `dataSource` and other beans: simply copy the configuration you already have and change bean ids so they won't collide. Everything should be mirrored except `<tx:annotation-driven/>`:

```
<bean id="dataSource1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <!-- ... -->
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory1" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager1" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory1"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource2" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <!-- ... -->
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory2" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager2" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory2"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager1"/>
```

And here comes the real problem: you now have two transaction managers bound to different session factories, which in turns are routed to different data sources. But `@Transactional` annotations will always use only one transaction manager - the one named `transactionManager` by default (note I explicitly pointed `transactionManager1`. This means that DAOs using second data source will participate in transactions started within first data source - this is obviously not what intended.

There are some workaround to this, like explicitly defining transaction manager name in `@Transactional` annotation (never tried it) or using `TransactionTemplate`, but as you can see problem should be well thought.

As for autowiring - if you autowire by name, name your fields the same as session factories or data sources ids and it should work - but is your smallest problem actually.

Comment: Spring 3 has added the ability to work with multiple transaction managers, by allowing you to give each of them a name. Details can be found here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-multiple-tx-mgrs-with-attransactional

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem. I have solved this by creating:
applicationContext.xml

```
<!-- dataSource properies -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:dataSource.properties" />
</bean>

<!-- MySQL -->
<bean id="mySQLdataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${mySql.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${mySql.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${mySql.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${mySql.password}" />
</bean>
<bean id="mySQLsessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mySQLdataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.victor.entity" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${mySql.dialect}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="mySQLtransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySQLsessionFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
    transaction-manager="mySQLtransactionManager" />

<!-- ORACLE -->
<bean id="oracleDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${oracle.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${oracle.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${oracle.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${oracle.password}" />
</bean>
<bean id="oracleSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.victor.entity" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${oracle.dialect}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
    transaction-manager="oracleTransactionManager" />
<bean id="oracleTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="oracleSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

in Dao injected sessionFactory with Qualifier annotation. In my case I had generic BaseEnity:

```
public abstract class BaseEntityDAOImpl<T extends BaseEntity> implements BaseEntityDAO<T> {

private Class<T> persistentClass;
@Autowired
@Qualifier("oracleSessionFactory")
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
}
```

and in service bean using annotation:

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true, value = "oracleTransactionManager")
public class UserService {

@Autowired
private UserDAO dao;
}
```

Averythings wokrs fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved it like this:

First of all, there should be different cfg.xml files for different databases. Then simply use Configuration object of the Hibernate whenever you want to connect to your second database.

```
Configuration config = new Configuration().configure("<complete path to your cfg.xml file>");
SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
```

I found this here : http://www.coderanch.com/t/468821/ORM/java/If-hibernate-cfg-xml-has

I am pretty sure that this can be extended to more than 2 databases.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I know I am late to response however, I solved the problem (How to connect multiple database using spring and Hibernate) in this way, I hope it will help :)

```
NOTE: I have added the relevant code, kindly make the dao and rest with the help of impl I used in the below mentioned code.

**web.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>MultipleDatabaseConnectivityInSpring</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
     <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener> 
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>


**persistence.xml**


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="localPersistenceUnitOne"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>in.india.entities.CustomerDetails</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes />
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="0" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/shankar?sslmode=require" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="username" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="localPersistenceUnitTwo"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>in.india.entities.CompanyDetails</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes />
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="0" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/shankarTwo?sslmode=require" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="username" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>


**dispatcher-servlet**


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    default-autowire="byName"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <!-- Configure messageSource -->

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="in.india.*" />
    <bean id="messageResource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
        autowire="byName">
        <property name="basename" value="messageResource"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>



    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryOne"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        autowire="constructor">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="localPersistenceUnitOne" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
        autowire="byName">
        <property name="basename" value="messageResource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryTwo"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        autowire="constructor">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="localPersistenceUnitTwo" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="manager1" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryOne" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="manager2" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryTwo" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="manager1" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="manager2" />

    <!-- declare dependies here -->

    <bean class="in.india.service.dao.impl.CustomerServiceImpl" />
    <bean class="in.india.service.dao.impl.CompanyServiceImpl" />

    <!-- Configure MVC annotations -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
</beans>



**java class to persist into one database**


package in.india.service.dao.impl;

import in.india.entities.CompanyDetails;
import in.india.service.CompanyService;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public class CompanyServiceImpl implements CompanyService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "entityManagerFactoryTwo")
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional("manager2")
    @Override
    public boolean companyService(CompanyDetails companyDetails) {

        boolean flag = false;
        try 
        {
            entityManager.persist(companyDetails);
            flag = true;
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            flag = false;
        }

        return flag;
    }

}


**java class to persist in another database** 

package in.india.service.dao.impl;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import in.india.entities.CustomerDetails;
import in.india.service.CustomerService;

public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "localPersistenceUnitOne")
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional(value = "manager1")
    public boolean customerService(CustomerDetails companyData) {

        boolean flag = false;
        entityManager.persist(companyData);
        return flag;
    }
}


**customer.jsp**

<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>SpringWithMultipleDatabase's</h1>
    </center>
    <form:form method="GET" action="addCustomer.htm"  modelAttribute="customerBean" >
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="firstName">First Name</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="firstName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="lastName">Last Name</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="lastName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="emailId">Email Id</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="emailId" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="profession">Profession</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="profession" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="address">Address</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="address" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
             </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>


**company.jsp**


<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>ScheduleJobs</title>
</head>
<body>
 <center><h1>SpringWithMultipleDatabase's</h1></center>
 <form:form method="GET" action="addCompany.htm"  modelAttribute="companyBean" >
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="companyName">Company Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="companyName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="companyStrength">Company Strength</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="companyStrength" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="companyLocation">Company Location</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="companyLocation" /></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
 </form:form>
</body>
</html>

**index.jsp**

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
 <center><h1>Multiple Database Connectivity In Spring sdfsdsd</h1></center>

<a href='customerRequest.htm'>Click here to go on Customer page</a>
<br>
<a href='companyRequest.htm'>Click here to go on Company page</a>
</body>
</html>

**success.jsp**

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>ScheduleJobs</title>
</head>
<body>
 <center><h1>SpringWithMultipleDatabase</h1></center>
    <b>Successfully Saved</b>
</body>
</html>

**CompanyController**

package in.india.controller;

import in.india.bean.CompanyBean;
import in.india.entities.CompanyDetails;
import in.india.service.CompanyService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class CompanyController {

    @Autowired
    CompanyService companyService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/companyRequest.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addStudent(ModelMap model) {
        CompanyBean companyBean = new CompanyBean();
        model.addAttribute(companyBean);
        return new ModelAndView("company");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addCompany.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView companyController(@ModelAttribute("companyBean") CompanyBean companyBean, Model model) {
        CompanyDetails  companyDetails = new CompanyDetails();
        companyDetails.setCompanyLocation(companyBean.getCompanyLocation());
        companyDetails.setCompanyName(companyBean.getCompanyName());
        companyDetails.setCompanyStrength(companyBean.getCompanyStrength());
        companyService.companyService(companyDetails);
        return new ModelAndView("success");

    }
}

**CustomerController**


package in.india.controller;

import in.india.bean.CustomerBean;
import in.india.entities.CustomerDetails;
import in.india.service.CustomerService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    CustomerService customerService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/customerRequest.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addStudent(ModelMap model) {
        CustomerBean customerBean = new CustomerBean();
        model.addAttribute(customerBean);
        return new ModelAndView("customer");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addCustomer.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView customerController(@ModelAttribute("customerBean") CustomerBean customer, Model model) {
        CustomerDetails customerDetails = new CustomerDetails();
        customerDetails.setAddress(customer.getAddress());
        customerDetails.setAge(customer.getAge());
        customerDetails.setEmailId(customer.getEmailId());
        customerDetails.setFirstName(customer.getFirstName());
        customerDetails.setLastName(customer.getLastName());
        customerDetails.setProfession(customer.getProfession());
        customerService.customerService(customerDetails);
        return new ModelAndView("success");

    }
}


**CompanyDetails Entity**


package in.india.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "company_details")
public class CompanyDetails {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "company_details_seq", sequenceName = "company_details_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "company_details_seq")
    @Column(name = "company_details_id")
    private Long companyDetailsId;
    @Column(name = "company_name")
    private String companyName;
    @Column(name = "company_strength")
    private Long companyStrength;
    @Column(name = "company_location")
    private String companyLocation;

    public Long getCompanyDetailsId() {
        return companyDetailsId;
    }

    public void setCompanyDetailsId(Long companyDetailsId) {
        this.companyDetailsId = companyDetailsId;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public Long getCompanyStrength() {
        return companyStrength;
    }

    public void setCompanyStrength(Long companyStrength) {
        this.companyStrength = companyStrength;
    }

    public String getCompanyLocation() {
        return companyLocation;
    }

    public void setCompanyLocation(String companyLocation) {
        this.companyLocation = companyLocation;
    }
}


**CustomerDetails Entity**

package in.india.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_details")
public class CustomerDetails {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "customer_details_seq", sequenceName = "customer_details_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "customer_details_seq")
    @Column(name = "customer_details_id")
    private Long customerDetailsId;
    @Column(name = "first_name ")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name ")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "email_id")
    private String emailId;
    @Column(name = "profession")
    private String profession;
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;
    public Long getCustomerDetailsId() {
        return customerDetailsId;
    }

    public void setCustomerDetailsId(Long customerDetailsId) {
        this.customerDetailsId = customerDetailsId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }

    public void setProfession(String profession) {
        this.profession = profession;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well. Finally I resolved my problem with this way:

First: add another dataSource and sessionFactory.

Second: add in the end of conf of hibernate a bean to every DAO that use another sessionFactory (implicit another dataSource). Like this:

```
<bean id="courseDAO" class="com.app.CourseDAOHibernate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory2"/>
    </bean>
```

**Every DAO that use a "sessionFactory" is inyected automatically, but in case of others DAO that use a others datasource you should inyect explicitely like that example.**

In the end I don't know if that is a successful solution but that is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add my example too. Maybe it will be usefull for another situations like getting data from one database and writing it to another with `EntityManager`.

So my **applicationContext.xml**:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- Connection 1 -->

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="unitRemote" />
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="business.domain" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@remote_host:1521:xe" />
  <property name="username" value="USER" />
  <property name="password" value="PASSWORD" />
</bean>


<!-- Connection 2 -->

<bean id="transactionManagerLocal" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryLocal" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactoryLocal" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceLocal" />
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="unitLocal" />
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="local.business.domain" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSourceLocal" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
  <property name="username" value="USER_LOC" />
  <property name="password" value="PASSWORD_LOC" />
</bean>
```

Package `business.domain` has entity classes for **remote** connection.

Package `local.business.domain` has entities for **local** connection.

Entities have annotation mappings for columns and relations.

Then **2 DAO** classes:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
public class RemoteDao {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName="unitRemote")
  protected EntityManager em;

  // ...

}
```

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional(value="transactionManagerLocal")
public class LocalDao {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName="unitLocal")
  protected EntityManager em;

  // ...

}
```

With this I could use `@Autowired` to inject DAOs in my **JUnit test**:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/config/applicationContext.xml" })
public class DaoTest {

  @Autowired
  private RemoteDao remoteDao;

  @Autowired
  private LocalDao localDao;


  @Test
  public void daoTest(){
    Entity entity = remoteDao.find(id);
    localDao.persist(entity);
  }

}
```

So here it's possible to use DAOs without service if this is needed for simple applications, tests or DB migration scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with something like below.

- 2 datasource, 2 sessionFatory, 2 transactionManger and 2 tx:annotation-driven. And each database db details in context
- One which needs to be used as default need to set primary = true. (in this oracleDataSource connection is set to default and abcDataSource connection required Transactional annotation)

```
<bean id="oracleDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:env/jdbc/oracle"/>
</bean>

<bean id="oracleSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" primary="true">
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="oracleSessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="abcDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="java:env/abc/oracle"/>
</bean>

<bean id="abcSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="abcDataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="abcTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="abcSessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/> 
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="abcTransactionManager"/>
```

The `transactionManger` for default session factory will be available by default (default is due to primary = true) and for other requires to specify in `Transactional` annotation

---

```
@Service("ABCRead")
@Transactional(value = "abcTransactionManager") 
public class ABCRead {
  @Autowired
  AbcImpl abcImpl;   // this will connect to abcSessionFactory

  @Autowired
  XYZImpl xyzImpl;  // This will connect to oracleSessionFactory
```

---

```
@Service
@Repository
@Transactional("abcTransactionManager")
public class AbcImpl {
  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

---

```
@Service
public class XYZImpl {
  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had another way to offer which works only with java classes and annotations.
Check it out at this SO post.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61232164/5681666