# Configuring Spring to useMultiple Data Sources

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, datasource, properties-file

I am trying to connect 2 different `schemas` within my `spring boot` application.

To do this I have got 2 different `data sources`. How should I configure this within my properties files?

I seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362546/how-to-use-2-or-more-databases-with-spring) which gave me an idea of how to do so. I currently have the following 3 property files in my application:

```
1. application.properties
2. hibernate.properties
3. multiple-db.properties
```

`application.properties` is currently empty. Below are the other 2 files:

**hibernate.properties:**

```
# Connection configuration
hibernate.connection.username= my_uname1
hibernate.connection.password= my_pword1
```

**multiple-db.properties:**

```
# Schema 1-Data source configuration
oracle.db.username1= my_uname1
oracle.db.password1= my_pword1
oracle.db.url1= my_url1

# Schema 2-Data source configuration
oracle.db.username2= my_uname2
oracle.db.password1= my_pword2
oracle.db.url2= my_url2

# JPA configuration
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

# Hibernate configuration
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
hibernate.connection.url=my_url

hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
```

Is this the correct approach? Do I need 3 `properties files`, or could I do this all in one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring documentation suggests a way to create primary and secondary data sources: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources

Each data source can be configured as described here: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-a-datasource

You can access them by using `@Autowire` from other beans. You can  associate a prefix to each data source so you can configure it in your `application.properties` or `application.yml` file.

You can also set one as primary.

Answer (score 0):

With Spring you can do this easily.

It would be something like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource_1"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/northwind" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource_2"  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/northwind_dup" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

You could also use your properties files and do something like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties"/>
```

And you could use only one file, or three. It is really up to you.