# Spring Boot JPA: How do I connect multiple databases?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I currently have one database connected and it is working. I would like to connect another (and eventually 2 more) databases. How do I do so? There should be a solution using only annotations and properties files.

I read this 
[Profile Specific Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lVT5.png)
and it sort of helps but I still don't know how switch from one profile to the other in the code during runtime. I'm assuming I need to be connected to one profile at a time before I try to retrieve/persist things from different databases.

I also read this question, [How to use 2 or more databases with spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362546/how-to-use-2-or-more-databases-with-spring), but I dont know how it works too well/ if it will apply. I'm not using a controller class and I dont know what that does. I'm also not sure how the config class they mention in the answer actually connects to the specific DO.

This is my application.properties file: (marked out username and password but its there in my file)

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.default_schema=dbo
hibernate.packagesToScan=src.repositories.LMClientRepository.java

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
spring.datasource.username=***
spring.datasource.password=***
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://schqvsqlaod:1433;database=dbMOBClientTemp;integratedSecurity=false;
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.jpa.database=dbMOBClientTemp
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

This is my application file:

```
package testApplication;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import fileRetrieval.InputFileParse;
import lmDataObjects.LMClientDO;
import lmDataObjects.LoadMethodDO;
import repositories.LMClientRepository;
import repositories.LoadMethodRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = LoadMethodRepository.class)
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = LoadMethodDO.class)
@EnableCaching
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(LoadMethodRepository lm_repo, LMClientRepository lmc_repo) {
        return (args) -> {
            List<LMClientDO> lmlist = InputFileParse.getMultiGroupfile();

            List<String> uniqueMediaIds = new ArrayList(InputFileParse.getUniqueMediaIds());

            for (int i = 0; i < InputFileParse.getUniqueMediaIds().size(); i ++){
                lm_repo.save(new LoadMethodDO(uniqueMediaIds.get(i)));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < lmlist.size(); i++){
                lmc_repo.save(new LMClientDO(lmlist.get(i).getClientId(), lmlist.get(i).getMediaId()));
            }
            //Here is where I would like to do stuff with data from the other database that I have not connected yet

        };
    }
}
```

I also made a new properties file called application-MTS.properties and I put data for the new database in there. Still unsure of what to do with it.

```
spring.datasource.username=***
spring.datasource.password=***
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://SCHQVSQLCON2\VSPD:1433;database=dbMTS;integratedSecurity=false;
```

Answer (score 4):

You will need to define multiple `DataSource` beans that each represent the various database connection resources you plan to use.

You will then need to add a `TransactionManager` and `EntityManagerFactory` bean definition for each of those `DataSource` beans.

If you intend to have each `DataSource` participate in a JTA transaction, you'll need to also consider configuring a JTA transaction manager rather than individual resource local transaction managers.

Comment: There is also a [sample project here](https://github.com/snicoll-demos/demo-multi-entity-managers)