# How to connect to multiple databases Spring Boot JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to model it off of this example https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources but they dont seem to be using a properties file, which is confusing me. How do they input the database name, log in info, and url? The way I currently have it is like this:

This is my config file for one of my databases: LM_Config.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "lmEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "lmTransactionManager")
class LM_Config {

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager lmTransactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(lmEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lmEntityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setDataSource(lmDataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(LM_Config.class.getPackage().getName());

        return factoryBean;
    }


    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource lmDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

}
```

This is my config file for one of my databases: MTS_Config.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "mtsEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "mtsTransactionManager")
class MTS_Config {

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager mtsTransactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(mtsEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mtsEntityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setDataSource(mtsDataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(MTS_Config.class.getPackage().getName());

        return factoryBean;
    }


    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.mtsDatasource")
    public DataSource mtsDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

}
```

This is my application.properties file. The main points of interest should be the ones starting in `spring.datasource...` and `spring.mtsDatasource...`

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.default_schema=dbo
hibernate.packagesToScan=src.repositories.LMClientRepository.java

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
spring.datasource.username=LOADdev
spring.datasource.password=lmtdev01
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://schqvsqlaod:1433;database=dbMOBClientTemp;integratedSecurity=false;
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.jpa.database=dbMOBClientTemp
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none 
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none

spring.mtsDatasource.username=mtsj
spring.mtsDatasource.password=mtsjapps
spring.mtsDatasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://SCHQVSQLCON2\VSPD:1433;database=dbMTS;integratedSecurity=false;
spring.mtsDatasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.mtsDatasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362546/how-to-use-2-or-more-databases-with-spring refer to this post

Comment: You didn't specify what your problem is and this question a duplicate. Review the answer @Priyamal linked to you.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources

Answer (score 0):

> they dont seem to be using a properties file, which is confusing me. How do they input the database name, log in info, and url?

The answer to this is that the example is using an embedded database, so there is no DB name, username, etc..

For your main question, review the similar questions in the sidebar, look at the documentation for `@Qualifier`, and come back with a more specific question.