# Connect to many MYSQL DB in the same web application

Tags: mysql, database, spring, hibernate

I have to create a Spring web application with the framework Spring MVC 4, Hibernate and MySQL.
In this context, I need to connect to multiple MYSQL databases in the same application.
Is it possible?
If so, can you help me find the right way.
Thank you.

***Edit:***
I'm attempting to access two databases simultaneously from the same Java class in Spring/hibernate. They are identical in terms of structure. and they both reside in the same mySql instance. I'll call them "myDatabaseA" and "myDatabaseB".

What i need is to connect to many Mysql DataBases. 
(e.g : The application is dedicated to several clients and each of them must have a different BD but all are mysql database:DB-CLIENT1, DB-CLIENT2,DB-CLIENT3,... )

Comment: Yes. Check how datasources are created and use them accordingly when setting up beans definition on top of them (adding the necessary datasource as dependency to be injected)

Comment: thank you for your reply,but can you better explain to me.
I'm a beginner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use 2 or more databases with spring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362546/how-to-use-2-or-more-databases-with-spring)

Answer (score 0):

For each database that you're connecting to, you need to setup javax.sql.DataSource and LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ,  JpaTransactionManager (if you're using JPA and Hibernate as your persistence provider) or LocalSessionFactoryBean and HibernateTransactionManager (if you're using Hibernate). And of course, your hibernate.cgf.xml for your hibernate related configurations

Comment: Okay, then my comment above would work. As I said, separate javax.sql.DataSource, LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and JpaTransactionManager objects for each database that you're connecting to and you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks a lot i will try your solution and i will see.