# Select data from 2 Data Bases without DB Link

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dblink, oracle

I'm trying to read data form 2 different Data Bases but I'm not allowed to use DB Links,
**is there another way to achieve this?**
I merged 2 results in a Java List but it doesn't work when i use group by with aggregation functions.

I had an idea but i have questions about it, my idea is select the data from 2 databases into a file then read the file as DB and apply aggregation functions here.

something like this
[image]

**is there a way to read a file as DB with hibernate?**

Thank you

Comment: implementnt the basic orm  interface layer yourself, it is a  rare and customlize required

Comment: In a  another way may be you can  write  data as a csv , and  use  sqlite or some else memory db to  read it . above step  save data into a file and  read it without basic db tools , why design like this ?not sure your real scenario .

Comment: Spring or Spring-Boot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use 2 or more databases with spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362546/how-to-use-2-or-more-databases-with-spring)